# Pass source HTML element to oncomplete function of PrimeFaces p:ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to pass the source HTML element as argument to JavaScript callback function of `<p:ajax oncomplete>`. I tried passing `this` which usually works in `onclick` and such:

```
<p:ajax ... oncomplete="callbackFunction(this)" />
```

It's not working. It seems to be a different object.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If the enclosing component is a widget, you pass the widget to the javascript function.. like <p:ajax listener="#{Bean.action}" oncomplete=" callBackFunction(PF('myWidgetVar'));"/>

Comment: In Which component you are using this ajax behavior?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi  h:commandLink

Comment: @ EvaMariam thx but this is not working...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In context of `oncomplete`, the `this` represents the PrimeFaces ajax  object which actually contains a lot of information. You could easily have figured out it by inspecting the object in debugger, or by passing to `console.log` which automatically pretty prints JS objects.

```
function callbackFunction(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
}
```

In case of ..

```
<h:form id="formId">
    <h:commandLink id="linkId" value="test">
        <p:ajax oncomplete="callbackFunction(this)" />
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

.. it'll look something like this in console (press F12 to get there):

```
accepts: Object
async: true
beforeSend: (w,i)
cache: false
complete: (w,i)
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
contents: Object
converters: Object
crossDomain: false
data: "javax.faces.partial.ajax=true&javax.faces.source=formId%3AlinkId&javax.faces.partial.execute=formId%3AlinkId&javax.faces.behavior.event=action&javax.faces.partial.event=click&formId=formId&javax.faces.ViewState=-4870787666399983047%3A-2006040112896840046"
dataType: "xml"
dataTypes: Array[2]
error: (x,i,w)
flatOptions: Object
global: false
hasContent: true
isLocal: false
jsonp: "callback"
jsonpCallback: ()
portletForms: null
processData: true
responseFields: Object
source: a#formId:linkId
success: (x,i,y)
type: "POST"
url: "/playground/test"
xhr: bD()
__proto__: Object
```

If you look closer, the `source` property is what you ultimately need.

So, just alter your call accordingly:

```
<p:ajax ... oncomplete="callbackFunction(this.source)" />
```